# Problem related to the SSH command

Tags: ssh

While I am trying to login to a remote device from my PC which runs Ubuntu 16.04, the terminal returns: **port 22: Connection refused**. Will be really grateful if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install openssh-server on the device you are trying to connect to?  Are you in a fire walled environment?  Does your network permit port 22 outbound to the Internet?

Comment: "port 22: Connection refused" means that, on the target system (the one you are trying to connect to) there is no program running and listening for connections to port 22. Is `sshd` running on the target? Is `sshd` configured to use a different port?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the `openssh-server` package is installed on the target machine :

```
apt policy openssh-server  
openssh-server:  
  Installed: 1:7.3p1-1  
  Candidate: 1:7.3p1-1  
  Version table:  
 *** 1:7.3p1-1 500  
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

That is from an Ubuntu 16.10 installation, you also can check it by executing this :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep openssh-server  
openssh-server                  install
```

If not installed, run : `sudo apt install openssh-server` on the target machine.

Allow `ssh` on the target machine : `sudo ufw enable` | `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp`